# Fire the datepicker onselect event manually

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

Can anyone tell me how do you trigger the onselect event of datepicker? My code is working well (pulling some data from a database based on the value of datepickers altfield) but when the page loads it doesn't trigger the onselect event on the current date and it doesn't display anything; so I would like to do that manually.

```
<script>
     $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker
    (
    {
          altField: '#sheet',
          onSelect: function load() {
            $(document).ready(function() {
                    $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'test.php',
                    data: {sheetid: $('#sheet').val()},
                    success: function(data)
                    {
                        $("#content").html(data);
                    }
                });

        });
        },
          firstDay: 1});
    </script>
```

Comment: try triggering a click event for your datepicker in the `body` `onload` function or `$(document).ready()` using `$('#datepicker').click();`

Answer (score 19):

You can trigger a `click` on the datepicker right after the set of the date.

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        altField: '#sheet',
        onSelect: function(date) {
            alert(date);
        },
        firstDay: 1
    });

    $('#datepicker').datepicker("setDate", new Date(2013,09,22) );
    $('.ui-datepicker-current-day').click(); // rapresent the current selected day

});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/DynuW/

Comment: I'm getting an error: `Uncaught Missing instance data for this datepicker`. Does anybody know why would that happen?

Comment: @ManojShrestha can you provide a sample please?

Comment: @IrvinDominin is it possible to use properties inside of onSelect, like altField: '#Date',

Answer (score 2):

I took this from the source code of the datepicker.js file. Note that `this` should be replaced with your input element (not the jquery object, the actual dom element). In my case, I was calling this from a keydown event.

```
// this is SUCH a hack.  We need to call onselect to call any
// specific validation on this input.  I stole this from the datepicker source code.
var inst = $.datepicker._getInst(this),
onSelect = $.datepicker._get(inst, "onSelect");
if (onSelect) {
    dateStr = $.datepicker._formatDate(inst);
    onSelect.apply((inst.input ? inst.input[0] : null), [dateStr, inst]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Best solution

```
var inst = $.datepicker._getInst($("#date")[0]);
$.datepicker._get(inst, 'onSelect').apply(inst.input[0], [$("#date").datepicker('getDate'), inst]);
```

Comment: Could you explain more why this is the "best solution," or at least how it works? I wouldn't consider the use of internal "hidden" functions of the jQuery datepicker module to be a good solution, let alone the "best".

Comment: Works fine for me!

Answer (score 2):

This is the only solution I found that also works for a datetimepicker

```js
var $calendar =$('#from');
$.datepicker._getInst($calendar[0]).settings.onSelect()//or onClose or any event
```