# How to set today's date in select boxes on page load using datepicker

Tags: jquery, date, datepicker

I have 3 select boxes, day/month/year.  If I load the webpage and click on a date using datepicker, the select fields are updated with the correct date.

However on page load I want the select boxes to be loaded with today's date.  I have tried to set today's date in datepicker on page load, but the select fields are not showing today's date, instead they show the 1st day, 1st month, 1st year from the select lists.

```
 <script>
$(function() {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
beforeShow: readSelected, onSelect: updateSelected,
minDate: new Date(), maxDate: new Date(2016, 12 - 1, 31)});


// Prepare to show a date picker linked to three select controls
function readSelected() {
$('#datepicker').val($('#selectMonth').val() + '/' +
    $('#selectDay').val() + '/' + $('#selectYear').val());
return {};
}

// Update three select controls to match a date picker selection
function updateSelected() {
var date1 = $(this).val();
console.log(date1.substring(0, 2));
console.log(date1.substring(3, 5));
console.log(date1.substring(6, 10));
$('#selectMonth').val(date1.substring(0, 2));
$('#selectDay').val(date1.substring(3, 5));
$('#selectYear').val(date1.substring(6, 10));
}

$('select').change(readSelected);
    $('#pickDate').click(function (e) {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker("show");
    e.preventDefault();
});
});
</script> 

 <script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
var currentDate = new Date();  
$("#datepicker").datepicker("setDate",currentDate);

});
</script>
```

Comment: setting date won't cause `onSelect` event to be triggered.

Comment: I added $('#datepicker').click(); but it still does not set the date

Comment: no reason it would, try something like: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18979888/1175966

Comment: tried that, the alert with todays date shows but still doesnt change the select field

Comment: could create a custom event on element that uses `updateSelected` as event handler, and trigger that event after setting date

Comment: so I could call readSelected and updateSelected after .click